# How soon before graduation should I start applying for jobs?

Tags: job-search

I am a PhD student graduating in September 2016. I just started looking for jobs, but I feel that when recruiters look at my CV and see that I am still 5-6 months away from graduation, they'll ignore me.

However, I can't just wait till 1-2 months before graduation, since finding a job is a long process (interviews, etc), and if I graduated without a job then I have to leave the US since I'm not a citizen.

This seems like a never ending problem. What do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes apply for jobs. It shouldn't matter if they see you are still 5-6 months away. If they are not interested then move on to the next. You never know, someone might actually have work or a position waiting for you.

Answer (score 4):

It takes approximately 1 month per every 10K of salary to find a job.  With a PHD, you should be looking at least in the 60k range, if not much much more.  Apply now.  You are actually BEHIND schedule.

Comment: Where's that number coming from? It's taken me two weeks or less to get a six-figure job in the past.

Comment: It's the average figure given out by the Department of Labor as a general guide for job hunting.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely apply. It is the CV that will be on file so make it a good one.  In your cover letter maybe even state your situation - you need a job to stay in the US.  They may low ball you but a job is a job.

Recruiters may ignore you as they want quick paycheck. Apply directly with companies.  With a PhD you probably have limited target group. 5-6 months out if they are looking for a PhD in your field will get their attention.